# How to change scope from Global to Store view for Price Attributes (By Default)

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the scope of price attributes which is Global by default. .actually i need to change different price for same products in different store views. Is it possible to change scope from Global to Store view for Price Attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Magento does not allow setting a per store price. However You can do this on a per website basis.

To do so, you need to go to `System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog`.

Then in the tab "Price", set price scope to Website instead of global.

On the product edit page, you can then set the scope on the upper left side to your website and then enter a per website price.

There are a free [extensions which will allow you a per store price,](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-view-pricing.html) and [this one is paid.](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-pricing.html)

Comment: but this extension don't work properly in the list or category page...

Comment: contact from their support team